# List.Except except with property of custom class

Tags: c#, list, linq

So i'm trying to make it as simple as possible, but stuck with finding the difference between my two Lists which both contain a Class called "Element".
Each "Element" has 3 Propertys - Path,Name,Size. Now i want to compare ListA with ListB if ListA has a Element with the property Name that ListB doesn't have.

I already tried it with:

```
List<Element> diffList = from first in ListA
    join second in ListB
    on first.Name equals second.Name
    select first;
```

which was quite weird since, ListA's Maximum count is at about 60.000 and the diffList had a count of 22 Million.
Also i tried it with:

```
List<Element> diffList = ListA
    .Where(w => !ListB.Contains(w.Name))
    .ToList();
```

This wasn't even possible to compile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MoreLinq's `ExceptBy`.

Comment: "Lists which both contain a Class called "Element". Each "Element" has 3 Propertys - Path,Name,Size."
"... if ListA has a Element with the property Name that ListB doesn't have."
Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: @mjwills How can i use it? I've added the NuGet Package already. Would it be like "diffList = ListA.MoreLinq.SequenceException... " or how?

Comment: Use the `Except` overload that expects an `EqualityComparer`, in which you can compare the property `Name` of your `Element` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except

Comment: @Grimm May i can not explain myself understandable enough, i'm not a native english speaker. I'll try it with a Backup example, assuming ListA is filled from the Source Directory and ListB is filled by the Destination. So if ListA has a new File it will be larger than ListB, and in this case i want to know which "Element" is different or missing in ListB, hope this is understandable.

Comment: @Chookees Neither am I - no problem :-) Now I understand that it's about the value of the property, not the property itself. So reckface posted a good answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

You want `Any()`, or `All()`, not `Contains()`

```
var diff= ListA.Where(e1 => !ListB.Any(e2=> e2.Name.Equals(e1.Name))).ToList();
// or better
var diff= ListA.Select(e => e.Name).Except(ListB.Select(e => e.Name)).ToList();
```

This may not be the best way for very large collections, and if you can avoid it, keep your collections as IEnumerables until you need to project your results.

Comment: The problem with this is, that diff is in my case also a List<Element> and i need to get the element by the property Name. In your Code i would get the Name as string but not the whole Element where the Name property not exists in ListB but in ListA.

Comment: @Chookees I  see. In that case, the first option.